# How to use next-css in next.config.js in combination with custom server Express

Tags: css, express, next.js

I have a nextJS app using express as custom server. I want to use next-css to include css files for styling. How do i setup this configuration?

Have created a next.config.js file containing:

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS()
```

My server.js files is based on the example given here:
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/custom-server-express/server.js

In package.json i'm including following:

```
"@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
"next": "latest",
"react": "16.4.2",
"react-dom": "16.4.2",
"webpack": "^4.22.0"
```

In the file i'm importing the .css file using `import './timeline.css'`
The css file contains:

```
.example {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
```

The error displayed in the terminal is:

```
> Failed to build
{ Error: (client) ./components/timeline/timeline.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> .example {
|     font-size: 50px;
|   }
 @ ./components/timeline/timeline.js 23:0-25
.....
errors: 
   [ '(client) ./components/timeline/timeline.css 1:0\nModule parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.\n> .example {\n|     font-size: 50px;\n|   }\n @ ./components/timeline/timeline.js 23:0-25\n @ ./pages/calender.js\n @ multi ./pages/calender.js',
....
```

To me it looks like the next.config.js is not loaded correctly. I'm in doubt on if i need to pass the configuration as an object to `const app = next({ dev })` or the next.config.js is loaded but the next-css is not working.

Comment: I'm not using `cssnext` but  `@zeit/next-css` https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css

Comment: Have you solved the issue in the end ? I am facing the same problem just now.

Comment: Not really ended up going with a different solution using material-ui and just used their examples to handle custom css.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code into your **next.config.js**

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({cssModules: true})
```

Comment: I did try that with same result. According to documentation this should not be necessary for the simple example.
https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-css

Comment: try this example : [https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-next-css](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-next-css)

Comment: The example is working. But i can not get it working in combination with next custom server.

Comment: try below code in **next.config.js**
    
     `const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
     module.exports = withCSS({
          cssModules: true,
          cssLoaderOptions: {
          importLoaders: 1,
          localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
       }
     })`

Comment: can you ellaborate on what localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]", will do?